# Hide single UITableViewCell seperator

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I am trying to hide the grey line (seperator) under two cells in my UITableView however I am having trouble.

I have a Grouped UITableView and this is my cellForRowAtIndexPath method

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:nil];


    if (indexPath.section == 0)
    {
        if (indexPath.row == 0) {
            // Date
            if (cell == nil)
            {
                cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
            }
            cell.textLabel.text = @"Date:";
            cell.detailTextLabel.text = currentDateString;
        } else if (indexPath.row == 1) {
// UIPicker
            if (cell == nil)
            {
                cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
            }
            cell.clipsToBounds = YES;
            [cell.contentView addSubview:datePickerForCell];
        } 
    } else if (indexPath.section == 1) {
        if (indexPath.row == 0) {
// Order No.
            if (cell == nil)
            {
                cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
            }
            cell.textLabel.text = @"Order No:";
            cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"001-01989";
        }  else if (indexPath.row == 2) {
// Location
            if (cell == nil)
            {
                cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
            }
            cell.textLabel.text = @"Completed:";

            CGFloat optionalRightMargin = 10.0;
            CGFloat optionalBottomMargin = 10.0;

            completedByTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(110, 10, cell.contentView.frame.size.width - 110 - optionalRightMargin, cell.contentView.frame.size.height - 10 - optionalBottomMargin)];
            self.completedByTextField.delegate = self;
            completedByTextField.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];
            completedByTextField.tag = 2;
            completedByTextField.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
            completedByTextField.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;
            completedByTextField.placeholder = @"Name";
            completedByTextField.text = completedByString;

            [cell.contentView addSubview:completedByTextField];
        } else if (indexPath.row == 3) {
// Hours Worked
            if (cell == nil)
            {
                cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
            }
            cell.textLabel.text = @"Hours Worked:";
            cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"4 hrs 26 min";
        }
    } else if (indexPath.section == 2) {
        if (indexPath.row == 0) {
// Description
            if (cell == nil)
            {
                cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
            }
            cell.textLabel.text = @"Description:";
        } else if (indexPath.row == 1) {
// Description Textfield
            if (cell == nil)
            {
                cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
            }
            [cell.contentView addSubview:descriptionTextView];
        }
    } else if (indexPath.section == 3) {
        if (indexPath.row == 0) {
// Materials
            if (cell == nil)
            {
                cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
            }
            cell.textLabel.text = @"Materials:";
        }
    }

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

I would like to hide the separators under the

// Description Textfield Cell

and

// Materials Textfield Cell (this has not been written yet, its just I wanted to make clear that there will be two cells I want to do this two not just one as it may affect your answer I guess...)

I have read about using tableview.separatorcolor but this changes the color of every cells separator color in the TableView.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know its not possible to just hide cell separator for some cells. It will be applicable for complete table view.

However you can achieve this by adding a transparent or white image view on those cells which you want to hide the separator. Keep the Image view size a little bit larger than the row height. May be it should help.

Otherwise in general its not possible to just hide cell separator for some cells. If you make any changes in a particular separator, it will be reflected in all table view cell separators.

Answer (score 0):

you can hide the line by set tableview  offset.

```
cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 45.0, 0.0, 0.0);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't trigger the separator to hide/unhide for specific cells for a UITableView. Rather, disable the cell separator altogether and add a custom separator to the cells you need. Add the following code to the cells you need to show a separator on:

```
UIView* separatorView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, cell.contentView.frame.size.height-1, cell.contentView.frame.size.width, 1)];
separatorView.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor]; // set custom color here
[cell.contentView addSubview:separatorView];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this line of code in your cellForRowAtIndexPath method-

```
tableView.separatorStyle=UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
```